# PHP datediff overday issue

Tags: php, datediff

I wish to get datediff between two times: first is in the evening (like 23:59:59) and the second is on new day (like 02:02:02). When using datediff, it doesn't show correct difference:

```
echo date_diff(date_create("02:02:02"), date_create("23:59:59"))->format('%H:%I:%S');
response: 21:57:57 (IS WRONG SOMEHOW)

echo date_diff(date_create("02:02:02"), date_create("00:00:00"))->format('%H:%I:%S');
response: 02:02:02 (ECHOS CORRECT TIME)
```

How could I get it work?

Comment: `var_dump(date_create("02:02:02"), date_create("23:59:59"), date_create("00:00:00"));` and __see__.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the date has changed, then you have to tell it that, or it will assume today. You can check it like this:

```
echo date_diff(date_create("tomorrow 02:02:02"), date_create("23:59:59"))->format('%H:%I:%S');
// 02:02:03
```

You can verify what the date_create is creating by just dumping it:

```
var_dump(date_create("02:02:02"));
// object(DateTime)(
//   'date' => '2019-08-16 02:02:02.000000',
//   'timezone_type' => 3,
//   'timezone' => 'America/New_York'
// )

var_dump(date_create("tomorrow 02:02:02"));
// object(DateTime)(
//   'date' => '2019-08-17 02:02:02.000000',
//   'timezone_type' => 3,
//   'timezone' => 'America/New_York'
// )

var_dump(date_create("00:00:00")); // 00:00 being start of day, not end
// object(DateTime)(
//   'date' => '2019-08-16 00:00:00.000000',
//   'timezone_type' => 3,
//   'timezone' => 'America/New_York'
// )
```

Comment: I think for this question it is also worth noting that 00:00:00 is not higher than 23:59:59 if the date is the same. it may clear up any confusion around the date time difference otherwise. (00:00:00 being the lowest time associated with a date not the highest)